# Return Statement only echos first array element

Tags: php, arrays, oop

When I run this bloc of code below only the first array element is echoed `Name1 : 4334232323`, rather than echo out all the elements.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
public $name = array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4");
public function display(){
foreach ($this->name as $names) {
    return $names .  ":" . mt_rand() .'<br>';
}
}

echo $names->display();
```

Comment: `return` ends teh loop

Comment: @Dagon it's correct, the return statement skip the rest of function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return` will exit the method once it met.
You could use the variable to hold the result and return at last.

```
public $name = array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4");

public function display(){
  $result = '';
  foreach ($this->name as $names) {
    $result .= $names .  ":" . mt_rand() .'<br>';
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `foreach` statement will fill `$names` with one entry at a time and loop through for as many entries as your array has.  The problem here is that you `return` during the loop which exits your `display()` function after the first name only.  If you want it to return a single string with all of the names, you should do something like this:

```
$output = "";
foreach ($name as $n) {
    $output = $output . $n . ":" . mt_rand() . '<br>';
}
return $output;
```